# how to use a variable in the entire java class

Tags: java

I am quite new to java and I have two questions!

First how can I make a variable usable entire a java class?
This is part of my method:

```
public void createID() {

 ObjectId Id = (ObjectId) documentClient.get("_id");
 StringID = clientId.toString();
}
```

And I want to use StringID in another method but it is either null (when I create public StringID =null in the main class) or not known.

My other question is that when I change the createID() to

```
public String createID() {

 ObjectId Id = (ObjectId) documentCleint.get("_id");
 StringID = clientId.toString();
 return Id; 

}
```

It says that the method should be void! I am looking for a way to return the variable from my method.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the whole class? For the second snippet: Try to return the `StringID` instead of `Id`

Comment: Please post the question with some more clarity with full code

Comment: "I am quite new to java" and to programming in general, it seems. Although you might get an answer to your question here, the short and specific answers we expect here are not really suitable for teaching novices the basics. Explaining them *properly* requires too much explanation. You might be better asking elsewhere. If you have a teacher, ask them. Or read a good book.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in order to define a class variable, you should define it under the class definition. For example

```
public class Example{

private int classVariable; // Variable to be reached from any method in class.

    private void someMethod(){
    }
}
```

In your `clientID` method, you assigned return type as `String`, but you are returning `objectId`. I guess you meant to return `StringID` variable. 
Also I guess, `documentCleint.get("_id");`
 should have been `documentClient.get("_id");`

You should try after correcting these syntax issues.

Comment: just a note: that is not a *global* variable, it's an instance variable . Global normally is used for a variable/value that can be used in the whole program, not only in one class.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1 :**

> First how can I make a variable usable entire a java class?

That `createID` limited to the scope of `createID()` method. To avail that in whole class, move them to top. (instance members).

**Question 2 :**

> It says that the method should be void!

```
public **String** createID() {

 ObjectId **Id** = (ObjectId) documentCleint.get("_id");
 StringID = clientId.toString();
 return **Id**; 

}
```

That is not the exact error. Return type is mistamatch there. That method should return a `String`  but you are returning `Id`  which is of type `ObjectId`. You might want to return  `StringID`

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable in more than one method you need to use  a global variable, to declare it simply declare it outside any method inside the class.

As for the second part of your question, it looks to me that you are not returning a string as id is not declared as a string